# Why is there an Application.Activate method for Word but not for Excel?

Tags: excel, vba, ms-word

A `Word.Application` object exposes an `.Activate` Method.

An `Excel.Application` object, on the other hand, only exposes an `.ActivateMicrosoftApp` method which performs a notably different function to "activate this particular application object".

Why isn't there an `Excel.Application.Activate` Method?

Comment: By the way, what means to Activate an application? To bring it foreground? To focus it? To maximize it? ...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Boring answer: because `Word.Application` and `Excel.Application` are entirely different types, with entirely different implementations.

`Outlook.Application` doesn't expose an `Activate` member either. Heck, it doesn't even expose a `Run` method.

I'm not even sure these `Application` classes share anything more than a type name. There *is* a basic "contract" that needs to be fulfilled (e.g. a VBE host's top-level object must have a `Name`), but things like `Activate` and `Run` aren't on that contract. As far as I know the "contract" has more to do with the plumbings than with the interface that's visible to VBA (e.g. thou shalt expose an `IStream` for all components, and implement an `IStorage` so the VBE knows where and how to persist the code).